# How to change a category when array is different?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I know that the title is weird but I don't know how to say what is my problem in one sentence.

So I've got to arrays and one file.
I combined two arrays so I can use `Math.floor(Math.random() * number)`

BUT I want change category.innerHTML when value of my file is from first or second array.

I try if Statement but I have that wrong I guess.

```
let fruit = ["apple", "mango", "watermelon", "peach", "banana"];

let vegetable = ["cucumber", "carrot", "potato", "celery", "radish"];

let categories = fruit.concat(vegetable);

let categoriesLength = categories.length;

let password = categories[Math.floor(Math.random() * categoriesLength)];

let category = document.querySelector(".category");

if (password <= categories[4]) {
  category.innerHTML = "<p>category: fruit</p>";
} else if (password <= categories[9] && password >= categories[5]) {
  category.innerHTML = "<p>category: vegetable</p>";
}
```

Comment: I think you are confusing array index, which is `<= 4` for fruits and `>=5` and `<= 9` for vegetables, with corresponding array items, which you can't apply comparison operators `>` and `<` to.
Maybe you can obtain your desired behaviour using `Array.prototype.includes` (see https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes_array.asp for documentation about it): `if(fruit.includes(password)) { ... } else if(vegetable.includes(password)) { ... }`

Comment: Why not `fruit.includes(password)` or `vegetable.includes(password)`? `password <= categories[4]` means “is `password` sorted above or equally to the string `"banana"`, lexicographically?”. That doen’t make sense.

Comment: ok, i'll try that

Comment: Another solution would be to first decide wether to show a fruit or a vegetable, and then chose from one of the arrays randomly

Comment: @JonasWilms That wouldn't produce the same odds of picking each option if the arrays become different lengths. For instance, if the `vegetable` array only had one entry, "carrot", then your approach would give "carrot" a 50% chance of being chosen, whereas this current code would give it a 1/6 (16.6%) chance of being chosen.

Comment: Jonas the thing is that  I don't want to choose if I show a fruit or a vegetable! I mean I want it to go randomly.

Comment: @IceMetalPunk `Math.random() >= fruits.length / (vegetables.length + fruits.length)`

Comment: @Dominika sure, but you could "choose randomly" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`password <= categories[4]` just lexicographically compares `password` with the string `banana`.

Instead, you can use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) or [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) like this:

```js
let fruit = ["apple", "mango", "watermelon", "peach", "banana"],
    vegetable = ["cucumber", "carrot", "potato", "celery", "radish"],
    categories = fruit.concat(vegetable),
    categoriesLength = categories.length,
    password = categories[Math.floor(Math.random() * categoriesLength)],
    category = document.querySelector(".category");

if (categories.indexOf(password) <= 4)
  category.innerHTML = "<p>category: fruit</p>";
else
  category.innerHTML = "<p>category: vegetable</p>";

// Supported only in ES2016+
if (fruit.includes(password))
  console.log("category: fruit")
else
  console.log("category: vegetable")
```

```html
<span class="category" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `indexOf(password)` to get the number and check if it is over the length of fruit.

```js
let fruit = ["apple", "mango", "watermelon", "peach", "banana"];

let vegetable = ["cucumber", "carrot", "potato", "celery", "radish"];

let categories = fruit.concat(vegetable);

let categoriesLength = categories.length;

let password = categories[Math.floor(Math.random() * categoriesLength)];

let category = document.querySelector(".category");

if (categories.indexOf(password) <= fruit.length) {
  console.log(password)
  console.log('fruit')
  category.innerHTML = "<p>category: fruit</p>";
} else {
  category.innerHTML = "<p>category: vegetable</p>";
  console.log(password)
  console.log('veggie')
}
```

```html
<span class="category" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
if (fruit.includes(password) ) {
  category.innerHTML = "<p>category: fruit</p>";
} else {
  category.innerHTML = "<p>category: vegetable</p>";
}
```

```js
let fruit = ["apple", "mango", "watermelon", "peach", "banana"];

let vegetable = ["cucumber", "carrot", "potato", "celery", "radish"];

let categories = fruit.concat(vegetable);

let categoriesLength = categories.length;

let password = categories[Math.floor(Math.random() * categoriesLength)];

let category = document.querySelector(".category");

if (fruit.includes(password) ) {
  category.innerHTML = "<p>category: fruit</p>";
} else {
  category.innerHTML = "<p>category: vegetable</p>";
}
```

```html
<div class="category"></div>
```